# discrete math proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let x be any one of the four students in a college.
Tamang attended only football games.
Raj attended both football and basketball games.
Venkat attended only basketball games.
Ram attended neither of the games.
Let $F(x)$ be “x attended football games” and $B(x)$ be “$x$ attended basketball games”,
where $x$ denotes one of the above students. Rewrite the following statements in
simple English sentence and use above information to determine its truth values.
(a) $ꓱ x$ such that $F(x) ꓥ B(x)$.
(b) $ꓯ x, F(x) ꓦ B(x)$
(c) $ꓱ x$ such that $¬ (F(x) ꓦ B(x))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

a-)There exists at least a student among Tamang, Raj,Venkat,Ram such that he attend both of the games.

b-)All students among Tamang, Raj,Venkat,Ram attended either football game or basketball game.

c-)There exists at least a student among Tamang, Raj,Venkat,Ram such that he did not attend any of the games.

a-) This part is TRUE because Raj attended both of the games.

b-)This part is FALSE because Ram does not attend any of them.

c-)This part is TRUE because Ram does not attend any of them